# error in the method of TreeSet

Tags: java, eclipse, treeset

I am using jdk7 and eclipse juno.I am learning TreeSet.while i am making a basic program of TreeSet it gives me error.I crosschecked with my booklet but i didnot found any change ,but my program is giving me error. This is my program

```
import java.util.TreeSet;


public class F 
{
 TreeSet<String> set=new TreeSet<String>();
set.add("hello");
set.add("abc");
set.add("test");
set.add("done")
System.out.println(set);

}
```

it gives me this error

```
D:\WORK\Set\src>javac F.java
F.java:8: error: <identifier> expected
set.add("hello");
       ^
F.java:8: error: illegal start of type
set.add("hello");
        ^
F.java:9: error: <identifier> expected
set.add("abc");
       ^
F.java:9: error: illegal start of type
set.add("abc");
        ^
F.java:10: error: <identifier> expected
set.add("test");
       ^
F.java:10: error: illegal start of type
set.add("test");
        ^
F.java:11: error: <identifier> expected
set.add("done");
       ^
F.java:11: error: illegal start of type
set.add("done");
        ^
F.java:12: error: <identifier> expected
System.out.println(set);
```

but during class this same program  ran.!!!help me!!!

Comment: Move all those code inside the main method. You can't have statements directly inside the class.

Answer (score 5):

Following statements Should be inside a method, not directly inside class.

```
set.add("hello");
set.add("abc");
set.add("test");
set.add("done")
System.out.println(set)
```

As @Dennis Meng commented, you are missing `;` for last add statement.

Comment: And he's missing a `;` on the last add.

Answer (score 1):

Missing semi-colon:

```
set.add("done")
```

...

```
set.add("done");
```

You also need to wrap the code in a method so it isn't directly inside of a class.

Answer (score 1):

You can not place your code inside the class itself. They should be inside a method or your main method, e.g.:

```
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class F {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeSet<String> set=new TreeSet<String>();
        set.add("hello");
        set.add("abc");
        set.add("test");
        set.add("done");
        System.out.println(set);
    }
}
```